# In or-tools, VRPTW, how can I incorporate the constraint that some stops should be visited by only one subset of vehicles?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

|  | vehicle 1 | vehicle 2 | vehicle 3 | vehicle 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| node 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| node 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| node 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

As could be seen from the matrix, a node could only be served by a specified list of vehicles. Node 1 should be served by vehicle 1 or vehicle 2, but not vehicle 3 or vehicle 4.

I tried to modify the solution proposed here ([In or-tools, VRPTW, how can I give each vehicle a different weight/score for each node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73146908/in-or-tools-vrptw-how-can-i-give-each-vehicle-a-different-weight-score-for-eac)), but it didn't work. Is there any way to add this type of constraint to VRPTW.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you share exactly what you tried? How you modified the code in the other question you provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you can use `routing.VehicleVar(node_index).RemoveValues([list of vehicle to remove])`

e.g. for node 1

```py
node_one_idx = manager.NodeToIndex(1)
routing.VehicleVar(node_one_idx).RemoveValues([3, 4]) # forbidd vehicle 3 and 4
```

note: vehicle index start at `0` so 3rd and 4th vehicle should be vehicle index 2 and 3...

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5a3b2f304438dad72b3a877b26e9cf2d9cf6f8a2/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L1499-L1501

Comment: Thanks for the response, It is very helpful. I could iterate through each location and remove those vehicle for each node. 
I also have a follow up questions regarding the specification of time window constraints.  I am wondering why the start and end of time windows have to be integers (7 or 11)? There could be case where a time window is between 7:30am-11:30am, which could be 7.5-11.5.

Comment: because the solver is using integer (`int64_t`) internally, if you want a 30min you can use 1 unit == 30min aka `7H30 -> 15`, and `11h30 -> 23`. Tips: try to keep resolution as the lowest possible.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5a3b2f304438dad72b3a877b26e9cf2d9cf6f8a2/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L856).

```
  /// Sets the vehicles which can visit a given node. If the node is in a
  /// disjunction, this will not prevent it from being unperformed.
  /// Specifying an empty vector of vehicles has no effect (all vehicles
  /// will be allowed to visit the node).
  void SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex(const std::vector<int>& vehicles,
                                  int64_t index);
```

Example use in py:

```
routing.SetAllowedVehiclesForIndex([0, 1], manager.NodeToIndex(1))
```